# Invalid Syntax on Python Dictionary

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, syntax

I'm getting an 'invalid syntax' error for line 8, even though I do the exact same thing on line 15, and there is no error.  I can't think why its erroring, because, to me, it seems like valid syntax.

```
while(True):
  chose = input("Phone or tablet? ")
  chose = chose.capitalize()
  if(chose == "Phone"):
    id = input("Which ID? ")
    Phone = {
      "Type": chose
      "Item Code": id
    }
    break
  elif(chose == "Tablet"):
    id = input("Which ID? ")
    Tablet = {
      "Type": chose
      "Item Code": id
    }
    break
  else:
    print("Incorrect response.")
```

Comment: So, if it stops at line 8, it will not reach line 15, therefore you don't know it works there. it would be nice to either put the nrs or specify which is nr 8 for your case. But in your case you missed separating the dictionary values pairs with a comma

Comment: just put comma after every key and value pair in dictionary

Answer (score 0):

```py
Phone = {
"Type": chose # Should be "Type": chose,
"Item Code": id
}
```

There should be a comma after `chose`. The reason you don't get an error lower down is because the error occurs at the top.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a comma after chose,

```
Phone = {
      "Type": chose,
      "Item Code": id
    }
```